# Callback not working properly. Needs to return the object property value

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

```
var studentMarks = {
    mathScore : 0,
    englishScore : 0,
    totalScore : null,
    computeMarks : function (mathScore, englishScore) {
        this.mathScore = mathScore;
        this.englishScore = englishScore;
        this.totalScore = this.mathScore + this.englishScore;
        console.log(this.totalScore);
    }
}

function setStudentScore(score1,score2,callback){
    callback(score1,score2);
}

setStudentScore(40,50,studentMarks.computeMarks);
print(studentMarks.totalScore);  //prints 'undefined'
```

The print statement should print 90 instead it prints `undefined`. What changes should I do to the computeMarks method ?

Comment: Try `studentMarks.computeMarks.bind(studentMarks)` as callback

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback for some help on this topic.

Comment: still didn't work @vp_arth. Any other idea ?

Comment: no help whatsoever @CrescentFresh . I am still confused in 'this'.

Comment: @ManojVerma, what exactly `didn't work`? add `console.log(studentMarks)` to callback.

Comment: @Redu : Yeah ! It was an interview question.Hence,had to deal with it.

Comment: As others have mentioned, where you have your callback defined originally, "this" points to window rather than studentMarks.

Comment: @Pytth In the callback `this` refers to the `studentMarks` object.

Comment: @Redu, only when called as `studentMarks.computeMarks`. When it passed by value, it will called as simple function without any context(with global context in not strict mode).

Comment: @vp_arth You are right... By callback I had meant `studentMarks.computeMarks()` alone... However when it gets passed as a callback directly it's definition get's assigned to an argument variable of the function which invokes it (`setStudentScore()` in this particular case) hence looses the scope. Instead shall be passed wrapped in an anonymous to work as expected. Shown in my answer.

Comment: @vp_arth's comment [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/jcnppetg/), you're messing something else up. You're not using IE 8 or something, are you? Also, the linked answer I posted explains everything, you need to make some modicum of effort here.

Answer (score 2):

```
setStudentScore(40,50,studentMarks.computeMarks);
```

You pass just computeMarks value as callback here. It is a function, not original object method. There is not information about to what object this function related.

When it will called, `this` will point to global object.

Try to bind context directly:

```
setStudentScore(40,50,studentMarks.computeMarks.bind(studentMarks));
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
setStudentScore(40,50,studentMarks.computeMarks.bind(studentMarks));
```

In JS, the thing called this, is the object that "owns" the JavaScript code. In your case, looks like it was the function calling it. You can use bind to tell it what does this refer to in your context. [Read this if you want](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: It still prints undefined @Scimonster.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
var studentMarks = {
    mathScore : 0,
    englishScore : 0,
    totalScore : null,
    computeMarks : function (mathScore, englishScore) {
        this.mathScore = mathScore;
        this.englishScore = englishScore;
        this.totalScore = this.mathScore + this.englishScore;
    }.bind(studentMarks)
}

function setStudentScore(score1,score2,callback){
    callback(score1,score2);
}

setStudentScore(40,50,studentMarks.computeMarks);
```

Working in console

Comment: It returns 'null'.

Comment: It's too early to bind, isn't it? object has not assigned to variable yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var studentMarks = function() {
 var self = this;
 this.mathScore = 0;
 this. englishScore = 0;
 this.totalScore = null;
 this.computeMarks = function (mathScore, englishScore) {
  self.mathScore = mathScore;
  self.englishScore = englishScore;
  self.totalScore = this.mathScore + this.englishScore;
  console.log(self.totalScore);
 }
};

function setStudentScore(score1,score2,callback){
callback(score1,score2);
}

var obj = new studentMarks();

setStudentScore(40,50,obj.computeMarks);
console.log(obj.totalScore);  //prints 90
```

Comment: It works but the constraint is I can't change the print to console. The only changes I can make are 1) In this.computeMarks function & 2) In the two lines where I'm calling the callback.

Comment: `can't change the print to console` - Are you kidding? Where is `print` implementation, if not?

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this

```js
var studentMarks = {
    mathScore : 0,
    englishScore : 0,
    totalScore : null,
    computeMarks : function (mathScore, englishScore) {
        this.mathScore = mathScore;
        this.englishScore = englishScore;
        this.totalScore = this.mathScore + this.englishScore;
        return this.totalScore;
    }
};

function setStudentScore(score1,score2,callback){
    callback(score1,score2);
}

setStudentScore(40,50,function(a,b){studentMarks.computeMarks(a,b)});
console.log(studentMarks.totalScore);
```